# GCP custom role creation failed with 400 code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I'm trying to create custom role on organization level, with permissions closer to roles/owner.

All unsupported actions for custom roles are filtered out.

Tried through console and Golang library.

Code sample:

```
func (r *roleEditor) createRoleInOrganization(req iam.CreateRoleRequest) (string, error) {
    createRoleCall := r.iamService.Organizations.Roles.Create(utils.CreateOrganizationPrefix(r.organizationID), &req)

    role, err := createRoleCall.Do()
    if err != nil {
        err := orkuserr.NewError(err, fmt.Sprintf("failed to create role in organization %s, role %s", r.organizationID, req.RoleId))
        return "", err
    }

    return role.Name, nil
}
```

I received error 
`role in organization xxxxxxxxxxxx, role role.for.user.xxxxx: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest`

I've tried to create same role through console, and received error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Here is a [list](https://jsonblob.com/72683e3a-3ead-11ea-be6c-370c11a83d37) of permissions which I tried to include into role.

Title in format - `role for user username`

Name in format - `role.for.user.username`

Stage - `GA`

Seems like problem with some(or one) permission from included permissions list

Comment: I have checked [the list](https://jsonblob.com/72683e3a-3ead-11ea-be6c-370c11a83d37) of the permission. And you are trying to add 2477 permissions to this custom role. I think you are hitting the limit of the custom role size. As a workaround, I would request you to split the role and using two bindings. 

Please let me know if this is not acceptable.